# 'Well defined' in a biological context

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, biology

> **Question**
>
> The following model is an approximation of the discrete logistic model $x_{t+1} = f(x_t)$ where
> $$
> f(x) = \begin{cases}
> \mu x,    & 0 \le x \le 1/2,\\
> \mu(1-x), & 1/2 \le x \le 1.
> \end{cases}
> $$
> For which values of the parameter $\mu$ is this model well-defined, i.e., it can be used iteratively without being biologically invalid?

This question was asked in one of my textbook for my maths biology course, it really doesn't seem very hard however I'm unsure what it means for the model to be 'well-defined' or 'biologically invalid'. I understand what it means for a function to be well-defined however in a biological way I'm unsure, does this mean choose μ such that there exists steady states? or just that for any real x$_0$ f(x$_t$) is real as well? I most definitely don't want the answer for this, I would simply like explaining what 'well-defined' would mean/look like in this context.

Comment: I don't think the notion of "biological invalidity" is a mathematical one...why not ask a Biologist?   Or, even better, ask whomever set the problem.  In this case, as we have no idea what it is that is being modeled, I can't imagine how we could judge the strength of the model.

Comment: We have to know what is being modelled. A common example might be, $f$ is not allowed to be negative, or $f$ is not allowed to exceed $1$. However, $f$ might represent anything, for all we know... so we can't say what is likely to be a valid output of $f$. Or perhaps, to be biologically valid, $f$'s iterations must converge.

Comment: @FShrike In this section of the textbook we are modelling population, hence I think I may have just answered my own question, we cant have μ to be negative nor zero, otherwise our findings would be irrelevant,  μ>0.

Comment: The question was worth $10$ marks, so perhaps it is more subtle than that. I don't know.

Comment: Even if we ignore the non-well-defined term "biologically invalid", if $f$ doesn't map $[0,1]$ to itself, then you can't really define a sequence by $f(x_t) = x_{t+1}$ unless you have some conditions on the initial condition $x_0$ to ensure the sequence never leaves the unit interval. Not all values of $\mu$ give you an $f$ with $f([0,1]) \subset [0,1]$.

Comment: My best guess (background in molecular biology) is that $\mu \in (0,2)$ is likely the desired answer. For $\mu$ in that range, the function ought to stay in the same range no matter how many iterations. Edit: in particular, in population modeling, you often are dealing with a percentage of some maximum population; here we seem to be setting that maximum to $1$.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on my comment:

From a mathematical perspective, to use an iteration, we need $f: [0,1] \mapsto [0,1]$. Otherwise we end up with values that can't be plugged back into the original function! It's clear that we need $\mu \in [0,2]$ for this to be true.

From a biological perspective, there are a couple of things to consider. First, presumably $1$ is a maximum population: a carrying capacity of some sort, which is why the function maps back to $[0,1]$. In addition, we need to consider what the value of $\mu$ implies biologically.

For instance, $\mu=0$ implies a population that will go extinct immediately. But in fact, for all $\mu <1, x \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$; so any population with $\mu<1$ will dwindle and die.

If we want to examine a system that is changing in population over time but not have species die out, we need $1<\mu \le 2$. Note that $\mu=1$ implies a total steady state somewhere below $x=1/2$. In addition, $\mu=2$ is going to force the function to settle into a specific subsets of orbits, so it's *possible* the instructor wants $1 <\mu<2$ instead.

I think my answer would be that *mathematically*, the function is well-defined for $\mu \in [0,2]$, but that *biologically* it is only *meaningful* for $\mu \in (1,2)$. That is, we can't derive any information from a system where $\mu \le 1$ even if it's mathematically consistent.

But this is at least partially opinion; ecology and population biology was never my strong suit, I was in molecular bio and dealt with proteins. Hey would you like to talk about Michaelis-Menten kinetics? Wait, where are you going...

Comment: This is a great answer. As a researcher in this space, my guess is that the professor wants a mathematical well-posedness answer. But since extinction and persistence are of interest in general, the classification of both regimes would be appropriate as well.

Comment: @Paichu Yes, sadly it's really hard to tell what a person who isn't here actually wants :)